# How to use string formats in C#?

Tags: c#

I have three textboxes in my control,for hour, minute and second.

User can input the values in text boxes.

I want to return the combined value in a format like HHH:mm:ss, how can I do that ?

For example if user puts the values 4,3,45 it should be `004:03:45`.

Please guide me to that, I tried with `string.Format("{0:000}:{1:00}:{2:00}",ht,mt,st)`

but it's not working, can I also use TimeSpan to achieve the same ?

Comment: "it's not working" does not really help anybody.  What is your output?

Comment: Your code output's 004:03:45 just fine on my end. What does it output on your end?

Comment: What culture is the default one on your PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guy here is always a help: http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

I just always end up coming back to that reference :)

Answer (score 2):

My golden reference for C# String Formatting is SteveX's blog entry on the topic:

http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Should have the answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string format for this purpose of string date time.......
you can convert the time into string and then match it with the concatenated string from three text boxes.......
i think this logic would work for you.